# My harddisk partition isn't visible under Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu!

Tags: partitioning, windows-7

here is what i did and what happened:

I reduced my Harddisk (D) size by 200 GB (Windows is running on C (separate SSD) and on D i have installed some programms and a lot of data) 
Now i installed Ubuntu GNOME (14.04) into this 200 GB. Everything worked fine and i could just start Ubuntu and Windows afterwards. Only thing that happend is that Windows cant display D anymore and the disk-management-tool on windows tells me that it is invalid. But when i start Ubuntu everything is perfectly where it should be my partition hasn't been overwritten or sth. like that.

So i don't think i have to repair sth. but all in all i really dont know what to do.

```
fdisk -l:

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9f73ac2b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63        2047         992+  42  SFS
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda2            2048    26570751    13284352   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda3   *    26570752  1045712895   509571072   42  SFS
/dev/sda4      1045714942  1465147391   209716225    5  Extended
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1045714944  1053712383     3998720   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6      1053714432  1465147391   205716480   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x9f73ac3c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048      206847      102400   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2          206848   250066943   124930048    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

parted -l:

Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      32,3kB  1049kB  1016kB  primary
 2      1049kB  13,6GB  13,6GB  primary   ntfs            diag
 3      13,6GB  535GB   522GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 4      535GB   750GB   215GB   extended
 5      535GB   540GB   4095MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 6      540GB   750GB   211GB   logical   ext4


Model: ATA M4-CT128M4SSD3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 128GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB  primary  ntfs         boot, diag
 2      106MB   128GB  128GB  primary  ntfs
```

Hope you can help me! (Yeah i noticed there are a lot of similar posts but in my case the partition doesn't disappear i just cant get access anymore from win7)

@Edit 
seems like chkdisk cant access d:\ when i use gParted it shows: Partition: /dev/sda3 (+keysymbol); File System: ntfs; Mount Point: /media/befoerster/Data; Label: Data; Size: 485.96 GiB ...; Flags: boot; (i really dont understand why this partition is mounted under media/bfoerster/Data (is this normal?))

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjD5M.png
gParted (i unmounted D now but it made no difference(D is the 485GiB Partition))

(You can always tell me if i missed some important details i will add them as fast as possible - if it is sth. i could just google plz give me a hint what i have to search for)

I really need your help i'm depending on my notebook and the stuff installed on it and i found no solution for my problem by my self.

Comment: in a german forum sb told me it is a windows problem, would it be senseful to repost this in the super user forum?

Answer (score 0):

did you try running chkdisk from Windows yet? You would start it from windows, it takes you to reboot and check it's partitions( consistency) before the start/booting( Windows). It helped me in similar cases.

Also I'd look at the flags with [gParted](http://gparted.org/download.php).

By the way funny your question be titled "partition disappeared" and your last sentence is it didn't( disappear).

Comment: seems like chkdisk cant access d:\\ when i use gParted it shows: Partition: /dev/sda3 (+keysymbol); File System: ntfs; Mount Point: /media/befoerster/Data; Label: Data; Size: 485.96 GiB ...; Flags: boot; (i really dont understand why this partition is mounted under media/bfoerster/Data (is this normal?))